# Bootstrap modal not showing as modal (Hot Towel)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, durandal

I am using durandal and the Hot Towel template for a project and I am having issues getting a very simple modal dialog to appear.

Here is my code:

```
app.showMessage('Test Message');
```

The dialog is added to the DOM:

```
<div class="modalHost" style="z-index: 1002; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="messageBox" data-view="durandal/messageBox" data-active-view="true" style="margin-top: -84.5px; margin-left: -895.5px;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 data-bind="html: title">Bleh</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="message" data-bind="html: message">Test Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" data-bind="foreach: options">
        <button class="btn btn-primary autofocus" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectOption($data); }, html: $data, css: { 'btn-primary': $index() == 0, autofocus: $index() == 0 }">Ok</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see the dialog has been added, but is not rendering as a modal.  It is just added to the bottom of my page (shown below).

[image: How modal appears]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I thought that it may be a stylesheet issue as I am using a template, but using the latest version of the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css from the bootstrap website doesn't resolve this.

### Update 1

When I just copy the HTML from the bootstrap tutorials into the view and click the 'lauch demo modal' button, the dialog opens properly.

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when I upgraded durandal to version 1.2.0 using nuget the durandal.css file was deleted!  I restored the file from my repository and voila!

[image: Working modal]

Comment: Yeah, AFAIK the messagebox component is a custom Durandal one that uses some of the Bootstrap styles and its own JavaScript; doesn't use the 'modal' class, uses 'messageBox' class instead, and also doesn't do a call to $().modal().